# Unterminated &lt;html:form tag JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have a small problem . When i use form without if condition like

```
    <html:form  action="/customerDepositReport.doo?showCustDepsForPrintingReceipt_action=showCustDepsForPrintingReceipt">
```

it works fine but when i enclosed it in my if else like

```
<% if(session.getAttribute("correctionEntry")!=null) { %>            
  <html:form  action="/preEntryCorrection.doo?entryCorrection_action=entryCorrection">              
  <input type="hidden" name="showDepositsList" value="">
  <% }else{ %>
    <html:form  action="/customerDepositReport.doo?showCustDepsForPrintingReceipt_action=showCustDepsForPrintingReceipt">   
<% } %>
```

It gives me an exception :

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/custmngmt/reports/viewCustomerDepositReportCriteriaForOldReceipt.jsp(356,0) Unterminated <html:form tag
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:132)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1646)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:976)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1247)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1421)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:194)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:360)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
>       org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>       org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1833)
>       org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1670)
>       org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:514)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

I have tested the condition , it does enter the if part but causes exception when going through the form tag . I don't get it. Some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**please, terminate tags porperly,**

`</html:form>` *into your jsp file* after `<html:form>` uses.

Your Error clearly says , Unterminated  (see it)

means, *you need to close every tag*`(here <html:form>)` after it's uses.

Comment: i have and anyways like i said , it works fine if i don't use if else .

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan correct but, you haven't contain body before use scriplet. but while using if...else at that time you are trying to add something into body... so that parts need to be remain into open-close tags.

Comment: Nice , i tried what u said and you were right but there's another problem now . 
i have
if(condition){
//form tag open 
whole body
//form tag close
}
else{
//form tag open 
whole body
//form tag close
}

Comment: i have to repeat the whole body twice because of this then . You know some other way?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan may i know what is difference between two content which is resided in if-block and else-block ?

Comment: yup and this sentence of yours gave me an idea . Why don't i just create a variable in my if else and then use it in my form tag for action attribute

Comment: should mark your answer as correct . Helped me :) . Thank u sir

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan correct, absolutely in a right direction.